# Replace '\n' with ' 'space in string using python

Tags: python

I have a string of the below form:

```
"\nMy objective is to work with a progressive &amp; innovative 
organisation where I can implement my skills, knowledge and \nachieve 
success.\n\nPHP\nSDE 2 \nQuikr\nZend\n(CommonFloor merged with 
Quikr)\nTasks\nTo develop Quikr Jobs portal\nLaravel\nTo develop 
intent-form to increase o\xef\xac\x84ine signups\nTo develop sales CRM 
tool\nJava\n \nSDE 1 J2EE\nCommonFloor\nTasks\nJava Spring\nTo work on 
hybrid mobile app for residential communities\nTo develop APIs for 
CommonFloor Groups\nJavaScript\n\nSDE 1 \njQuery\nIDrive India Pv
Ltd.\nTasks\nAngular JS\nTo develop APIs for cloud storage\nTo add  front-end functionalities for online backup and data sync\nGulp\n\nSDE 1 "
```

I want to replace `'\n'` with `space` using python. I tried this command:

```
doc=doc.replace('\n',' ')
```

but it's not replacing '\n' with space. How I can do this?

Comment: In my world it works. Also if it's multyline string consider to use `"""text"""`

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? That is not an adequate problem specification.

Comment: And what is the error?? or what is the output instead?

Comment: did you try str.replace? `str.replace("\n", " ")` should do the trick

Comment: .replace('\n',' ') should work

Comment: What is \n in your example, new line or 2 symbols: backslash and 'n'? if 2nd, then write `str.replace("\\n", " ")`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your string seems to be multiline so you need triple quotes `'''`. This code works:

```
doc = '''\nMy objective is to work with a progressive &amp; innovative 
organisation where I can implement my skills, knowledge and \nachieve 
success.\n\nPHP\nSDE 2 \nQuikr\nZend\n(CommonFloor merged with 
Quikr)\nTasks\nTo develop Quikr Jobs portal\nLaravel\nTo develop 
intent-form to increase o\xef\xac\x84ine signups\nTo develop sales CRM 
tool\nJava\n \nSDE 1 J2EE\nCommonFloor\nTasks\nJava Spring\nTo work on 
hybrid mobile app for residential communities\nTo develop APIs for 
CommonFloor Groups\nJavaScript\n\nSDE 1 \njQuery\nIDrive India Pv
Ltd.\nTasks\nAngular JS\nTo develop APIs for cloud storage\nTo add  front-end functionalities for online backup and data sync\nGulp\n\nSDE 1'''
doc = doc.replace('\n', ' ')
```

Answer (score 10):

```
doc=''' your text '''
doc=doc.replace('\n',' ')
print doc
```

Comment: you should provide a text with your answer, not just pure code. And to me your code does not solve the problem as there is no new line which could be replaced and it wouldn't be replaced with a space (' ').

Comment: ok, thank you, this is my first time, I'll see to it from next. It should have been a (' ') instead of ('') I missed that.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is:

```
doc = doc.split('\n')
doc = " ".join(doc)
print doc
```

Comment: above logic will work ok " sting ..."  also, no need to be convert to """ / ''' .